# How to get PHP_excel working on windows wamp stack (ampps)

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-extension, ampps, libxl

I am trying to add this extension to my php 5.3 running under Ampps localhost on windows: https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel

I have downloaded the pre-built windows packages which contains:

```
libxl.dll
php_excel.dll
php_excel.pdb
```

I have put php_excel.dll in the extension folder and updated the php.ini but its telling me: *unable to load dynamic library the specified module could not be found*

I tried to also include the libxl.dll but it says its not a php library.

Where do I put the libxl.dll file? and where do I put the php_excel.pdb.

How do I configure this to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working:

```
Copy libxl.dll to C:\xampp\apache\bin\ and C:\xampp\php\.
Copy php_excel.dll to C:\xampp\php\ext\.
```

add this to php.ini, and restart apache.

```
[excel]
extension=php_excel.dll
```

Comment: in my case it was ampps\php.5.3